# Generate mixed-case random password in PHP

Tags: php

Here is a list of random passwords:

```
xFn2zhgH
NqnzZtJQ
3Lh4nBkf
N8zyq4TF
wRzZTxDV
yJhL6CFH
3KdgtRX4
ypgGXdY2
Y9zN7cn2
zcy8LKNp
```

I need to have some kind of function that will create a password similar to the format of these existing passwords.  Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: $password = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);

Answer (score 2):

```
function create_password ($len)
{
  $pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $str = '';
  for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++)
  {
    $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
  }
  return $str;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash with the current date/time

```
$hash = md5(date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));
```

Then truncate it to the number of chars you want.

Comment: The current date time is *not* "random" and thus this solution can be exploited.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in PHP, here is a simple code to generate random password:

```
function randomPassword($length = 8) {
    $password = '';
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $limit = strlen($characters) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $password .= $characters[rand(0, $limit)];
    }
    return $password;
}
```